# Using Two Columns as Discriminator

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

Is it possible to use two columns as a discriminator. For instance, something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
          .HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
          .HasValue<Models.SpecificJob>("attack");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
          .HasDiscriminator<string>("Domain")
          .HasValue<Models.SpecificJob>("fire_nation");

    }
```

Right now, it seems like it takes only the very last discriminator and ignores the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  A Discriminator indicates the subtype, and EF (and .NET) do not support [Multiple Inheritence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

But you can (and should) just use normal properties, one for the "Type" and one for the "Domain".

You can add "Getters" for filtered subsets of your entities.  EG:

```
    class Db : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
        public IQueryable<Job> AttackJobs => Jobs.Where(j => j.Type == "attack");
        public IQueryable<Job> FireNationJobs => Jobs.Where(j => j.Domain == "fire_nation");
 . . .
```

Comment: Is there a way, then, to modify so that the GET, Update, etc queries only draw from records that match that type and domain? Pretty new to the .NET Core ecosystem here, but I'm assuming maybe there's some custom code you can add to the context for that?

Comment: You can add special "get" methods, but you would use the base DbSet<Job> to add any new job.